# Forwarding a link to an anchor tag on main page

Tags: html, redirect, hyperlink, web, anchor

I need some help forwarding a link to an anchor tag on my page. For example, I want the following:

http://www.example.com/anchor forwards to http://www.example.com#anchor

I also tried setting up a 301 Redirect for this, but no luck there either i.e.

Redirect 301 /anchor http://www.example.com#anchor

Answer (score 0):

Putting this in http://www.example.com/anchor.php should work.

```
<?php
header("Location: http://www.example.com#anchor");
exit;
?>
```